# Перенос чертежа из Компас3д на свой сайт

Tags: javascript, php, веб-программирование

Всем здравствуйте, имеется чертёж в Компасе, какие есть способы переместить чертёж на свой сайт? Нужно чтобы осталась возможность приближать-отдалять чертёж на сайте без изменения масштаба сайта (т.е. отдельное окно с чертежом) и так сказать перемещаться по чертёжу зажимая ЛКМ. Есть ли готовые решения или нужно самому придумывать велосипед?) Кто может толкнуть в нужном направлении? Заранее спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Думаю надо посмотреть, в каких форматах может сохранить чертёж Компас и гуглить какие-то модули для отображения таких файлов на сайте. В крайнем случае можно в ПДФ сохранять и дать людям ваш чертеж посмотреть.

Comment: сохраняешь в картинку jpeg, а её можно зумить на сайте, яваскрипт-плагинов куча

Comment: Проблема в том что поверх чертежа хочу сделать кликабельные точки которые должны быть прицеплены к определённым местам и двигаться вместе с чертежом

Comment: Представьте гугл карты к примеру. Там карта, она масштабируется точки кликабельны. Какая технология используется в них?

Comment: @HistoryLifeNSK: наверняка Компас умеет сохранять чертежи в формате SVG, а веб-браузеры поддерживают этот формат. Так как это вектор и параметрика, то ни с масштабированием, ни с добавлением интерактивности проблем не должно возникнуть.

Comment: @HistoryLifeNSK гугл карты разрабатываются не один год и большой корпорацией. Там нет какого-то плагина или какой-то одной технологии - там ВСЕ!